# Is it allowed to leak pointers of thread local variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-lawyer

I am currently trying to better understand thread local storage in C++. To this end I wrote the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

thread_local int thread_index;

std::vector<int*> pointers;
std::mutex mutex;

void show_index()
{
  {
    thread_index = 0;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mutex);

    pointers.push_back(&thread_index);
  }

  while(true)
  {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mutex);
      std::cout << "Index of thread "
                << std::this_thread::get_id()
                << " : "
                << thread_index
                << std::endl;
    }
  }
}

void change_index()
{
  while(true)
  {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mutex);

      std::cout << "Thread "
                << std::this_thread::get_id()
                << " is changing indices"
                << std::endl;

      for(auto& pointer : pointers)
      {
        ++(*pointer);
      }
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;

  for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
    threads.push_back(std::thread(show_index));
  }

  threads.push_back(std::thread(change_index));

  for(auto& thread : threads)
  {
    thread.join();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

As can be seen the address of a `thread_local` variable is *leaked* into the program and the thread local variables are *inadvertedly* changed by another thread. All access to the global state is protected by a `std::mutex`, so there should not be an races. Indeed, I see the following expected output:

```
Index of thread 140443980949056 : 0
Index of thread 140443887072832 : 0
Index of thread 140443989341760 : 0
Index of thread 140443980949056 : 0
Index of thread 140443887072832 : 0
Index of thread 140443989341760 : 0
Thread 140443972556352 is changing indices
Index of thread 140443980949056 : 1
Index of thread 140443989341760 : 1
Index of thread 140443887072832 : 1
...
```

My question is: What does the standard say about accessing thread local variables from *another* thread? Is a thread local variable merely a pointer to memory that is guaranteed to be unique for each thread, or does the standard mandate "thread local" access as well?

Comment: Why do you say they are "inadvertently" changed? One thread deliberately provides the address of an object to another and the other thread modifies the object through that pointer. In what sense is that inadvertent? Threads share the same view of memory.

Comment: Well, this was supposed to be a MWE. Maybe in a more complex piece of code it really happens inadvertently rather than intentional.

Comment: I suppose. But all you are passing to the other thread is a pointer. You aren't passing anything `thread_local` to the other thread.

Comment: Personal opinion: If you _really_ want to understand `thread_local`, then you should understand that `thread_local` usually only makes sense if the variable has static extent, and then you can go read about all of the ways in which static allocation limits your ability to test, modify, and re-use code. Also, `thread_local` can cause problems if it's used anywhere within code that could be called by tasks submitted to a thread _pool._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's precisely the same as any other local object. All threads share the same view of memory and a function or thread can pass a pointer to a local object to another thread or function if it wants to. If you do this, it's you responsibility to ensure there are no race conditions and an object isn't accessed outside of its lifetime.

I disagree that anything is "inadvertently" changed here. Threads have the same view of memory, so a pointer to an object in one thread will point to the very same object in another thread during that object's lifetime.

The situation is the same with objects on a thread's stack. They are local in the sense that each thread has its own stack. But it is perfectly legal for one thread to give another thread a pointer or reference to an object on its stack. Thread safety and lifetime issues are, as always, your responsbility.

Answer (score 2):

Thread local access is not required. However, there is a subtlety you want to be aware of with your example code:

Data in thread local storage is deleted when the owning thread exits. This means that the posted code is not guaranteed to work. If a `show_index` thread exits before the `change_index` thread the data accesses in `change_index` might be invalid and that pointer may be pointing to garbage or another threads TLS. Because the threads involve infinite loops, they will never terminate on their own. However, when you kill the program `show_index` thread may be killed right before a `change_index` thread reads/writes the pointer.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: I would think that in the example above no thread ever exits unless I kill the program. After all, the threads all consist of infinite loops, correct?

Comment: I missed the while loop.... my bad, you are correct. I think there is still a chance for a bad access at the time of termination - I don't think you can rely on the order in which threads are terminated. One thread may be killed just before another thread reads the pointer. I've edited my answer to describe this better.